# Meteor.js: Submitted posts are not showing when deployed on meteor.com and modulus.io servers, even though everything works fine on my computer

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I think I am missing something simple. I have deployed my Meteor application to two sites:

http://servyc.meteor.com 
http://servyc-9594.onmodulus.net/

In both cases, it seems that the database does not send data to the client. For example, if you sign up and post an offer or request on the site, it does not show up on the bottom of the home page, which it should. I have no way of checking whether the data was actually posted for  `servyc.meteor.com`. But I can check for `servyc-9594.onmodulus.net`, and the data does get entered into the database (hosted ad `mongohq`).

What is odd is that this site works fine when I run it on my Mac: data gets posted AND gets sent to the client. Do I need to do something special when I deploy? Maybe the `Meteor.subscribe()` commands are ineffective when deployed without some special setting? What I find strange is that for the modulus host, the data gets into the database but doesn't get sent out.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you publishing as well as subscribing? Have you removed `autopublish`?

Comment: Yes, I am subscribing on the client, and publishing on the server. I removed autopublish on my Mac before deploying to both hosts (meteor.com and modulus.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like you haven't handled the case where data isn't yet available on the client.

I tried to log in and that works showing your subscription/publish functions are fine. If you check your javascript console you can see a couple of errors on how something is undefined or so.

The reason for this is when meteor loads up on the browser, all the collections are empty. You need to take this into consideration when displaying data to allow for it to be empty and not read stuff e.g

```
var myDocument = Docs.findOne();
return myDocument.date;
```

If you do something like this initially `myDocument` doesn't exist, its still null. It'll be available a couple of seconds later when the data is finally ready from the client. You just need to handle this case without causing an error.

This happens on remote sites and not on your local mac because there is additional latency to those sites so on your local mac it might not happen because the data is already available so quickly. But on a remote site it takes a bit of extra time because its further away from your computer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you suggest how I would handle this case? Should I implement a delay in the code (using something like `setTimeout`, or another equivalent of python's time.sleep() command)?  I think the best solution is to make the client browser wait until data is available before meteor loads up on the browser. Cheers,

Comment: Nothing like that you just need to check the variable exists, e.g `return myDocument && myDocument.date`. Since meteor is reactive it'll automatically adjust with the changes. If you have something that runs on startup put it in a `Deps.autorun` so it can run again when new data arrives

Comment: I tried putting my `Meteor.subscribe()` statements in Deps.autorun blocks, but that didn't do the trick. I don't see why the collections variables don't automatically update - I thought that these are reactive sources by default. Could you point me to some resources for figuring this out? Also, I have placed the lat & lng coordinates Session variable that are made persistent using Amplify... but these are not loading quickly enough. Should I use deps.autorun to make these session variables reactive? Thanks!

Comment: Yes if you have a bunch of code that just runs and does something thats not in a template helper you need it to be in a Deps.autorun block of code to be reactive too. Template helpers are taken care of automatically. You mentioned you're using maps so i'm not too sure you can use template helpers for this since you would be interacting with google's api? You could place them in a Deps.autorun block (see http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun). There are also a couple of google maps examples (see the end of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761042/meteor-js-and-google-maps)