# Loading Google Map using Meteor JS

Tags: google-maps, meteor

Using Meteor 0.8.2 and Google Maps API version 3.0

HTML Doc: (I omitted my google maps key but I have a valid one)

```
<head>
  <title>myapp</title>
   <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=####&sensor=false">
type="text/javascript">
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

js doc:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to myapp.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input': function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

I have taken the boilerplate code largely from resources that I have found online. Most of these resources are about a year old, so I am wondering if there may be compatibility issues between versions of the software.

I am wondering how to load the map working with the code above.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I don't see any attempt in your code to load the map? If you are looking for a tutorial for google maps api, then I'm sure you can find one. Why do you show us the meteor boiler plate code if it has nothing to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Add the html element to the hello template:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 300px; width: 300px"></div>
```

Add the normal maps loader to the rendered callback:

```
Template.hello.rendered = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
};
```

This same code would have worked as far back as Meteor had the rendered callback, so nothing has changed.

All of the code is readily available on the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) page and there are already a few questions on this topic, including meteor specific [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761042/meteor-js-and-google-maps).