# Put javascript code from head tag into meteor js files

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, google-api, file-structure

Okay I'm not really sure how to explain this clearly so the title might have been slightly confusing. I have some code for using the google maps api from w3 schools (http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_basic.asp) which is shown as going in the head tag of the html file. But I am also trying to use Meteor.js for another part of the app and it separates the javascript code into another .js file. So basically I am wondering how/where to put the javascript code from the head tag into the meteor .js files. I tried to put it directly in but I think it needs the other script tag to go with it because it has some variables that weren't defined if I moved it. So how can I move the javascript code and make sure that the variables are still defined? Should I move the script src tag with it somehow?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"> </script>
<script>
    //javascript code I want to move is here
</script>
```

I've also read something about dynamically loading the javascript with jQuery or something but I'm not sure I understand how that would work?

Here is the github repo of the code but I don't think you'll need it: https://github.com/2016rshah/meteor/tree/master/FlightNews

Sorry for asking such a silly question I am new to web-dev and I've never really faced problems like this with Java or Python because you can just import wherever you need to. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761042/meteor-js-and-google-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a silly question. Others have had the same problem, too. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761042/meteor-js-and-google-maps) question has two good answers that will solve your problem. In the comments you'll also find a blog post about the issue.

However, you may also want to consider using a Meteor package that was developed to ease integration of Google Maps into Meteor. One example is [`googlemaps`](http://atmospherejs.com/package/googlemaps) but there are also others. There's also an [example](https://github.com/drewjw81/meteor-googlemaps/tree/master/examples/basic) showing you how to use the package.