# Meteor.js Google Maps initialize

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, initialization

I'm having issues initialising my google map with markers coming from the database in Meteor.
I've put console.log messages everywhere to test it - it seems to be very inconsistent - with sometimes the markers being created and loaded - and at other times it enters the initialize function, but it won't enter the loop to create the markers.  I have a waitOn subscription in the router to make sure that the data is loaded and is available before running the initialize function.

html template:

```
<template name="mapGoogle">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:900px; height:420px;"></div>
</template>
```

client js:

```
Template.mapGoogle.rendered = function(){
  Session.set('loading', true');
  initialize();
}

var initialize = function(){
console.log('inside initialize');

var latitude = 22.2924391;
var longitude = 94.1967784;

var map; var icon; var lat; var lng; var icon;
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var markers = [];

var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { hue: '#3cff00' },
      { visibility: 'simplified' },
      { gamma: 0.5 },
      { weight: 0.5 }
    ]
  },
  {
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [
      { visibility: 'on' }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    stylers: [
      { color: '#83bbdd' }
    ]
  }
];

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
  {name: "Styled Map"});

// Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
// to the map type control.
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 2,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'map_style']
  }
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

  var sharkFin;

  Sharks.find().forEach(function(shark){
    console.log('inside shark for loop)
    sharkFin = '/images/fins/shark_fin.png';
    latShark = shark.latitude;
    lngShark = shark.longitude;

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(latShark, lngShark),
      map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: sharkFin,
    });
  })

  Airlines.find().forEach(function(airline){

    console.log('inside airline for loop');

    icon = airline.iconAir;
    lat = airline.latitude;
    lng = airline.longitude;
    title = airline.title;
    content = airline.content;
    if(airline.webLink){webLink = airline.webLink}else{webLink=""};

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: icon,
      title: title,
      content: content,
      webLink: webLink
    });

    var listener3 = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(marker) {
      console.log('inside marker listener');
      return function(){
        $('#content').find('div').remove();
        if(webLink==""){
          $('#content').append('<div><h1>'+ marker.title+'</h1><br>'+ marker.content+'<div>');
        }else{
          $('#content').append('<div><h1>'+ marker.title+'</h1><br>'+ marker.content+"<br><br>More information can be found on the airline's website <a href="+marker.webLink+'>here</a>.<div>');
        }
      }
    }(marker)); //use closure for access to variables.
  });
  console.log('session variable set to false');
  Session.set('loading',false);
```

}

Router.js -

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('mainPage', {path:'/',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
      console.log('inside router session to true');
      Session.set('loading',true);
    },
    waitOn: function(){
      return [Meteor.subscribe('airlines'),
              Meteor.subscribe('sharks')];
    }
  });
});
```

It seems as though on the first rendering of the page - the markers are created and animated correctly on the map. However, if I refresh the page, sometimes the markers are created and other times they are not.

I have also tried using google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize) on the mapGoogle rendered js code. But still the same problem exists.

Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: Additional info - looking at the console logs. The code will always enter the initialize() function upon a page refresh, but it sometimes will not enter the marker creation loop.

Comment: How are you loading the google maps API ? Are you using setting up the default `loading` hook using `Router.onBeforeAction("loading");` ? Have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536203/google-maps-v3-with-meteorjs-loading-sync-issue/25536484#25536484

Comment: "it sometimes will not enter the marker creation loop." => looks like a subscription not yet ready when Template.rendered is called.

Comment: @saimeunt. agreed on statement 2. when i output the count of the airlines/sharks -it doesn't load when the count is returning 0. But now I am confused - I thought the waitOn function in the Router will resolve this. i.e. the page shouldn't load at all until the subscription is ready and completed first?

Comment: oh -  i see what you mean. I need to setup iron-router's own default loading hook for it to work and wait on the data subscription - instead of my own session variable?

Comment: didn't see the point of your Session loading variable as it's not actually used anywhere in the code (no Session.get ?). And yeah, setting up correctly waitOn is not enough, you need to specify that you want to use the default loading hook, this is a common gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

@Saimeunt is correct.

I needed to add default loading hook for iron-router using Router.onBeforeAction("loading").
Otherwise the waitOn subscriptions are not really applied and the page is loaded before the data has been loaded up.